# Running Erlang code and projects in Yaws (ebin_dir)

Tags: erlang, yaws

I'm exploring Yaws and I've read the Yaws manual and the Building Web Applications with Erlang book. I've followed every step in the book's last chapter where a `multi_cast` app is built, but I can't run it. I believe it's the Erlang code which isn't being found or used.

I've got a project dir in my home directory and I've pointed Yaws `docroot` for this particular Virtual Server to my project directory where a `htdocs` dir with the `.yaws` files reside.

```
<server localhost>                                                                                                                     
  port    = 8001
  listen  = 127.0.0.1
  docroot = <my_path_here>/erlang_yaws/multi_cast
</server>
```

and I've changed the `ebin_dir` to also point to the project´s `ebin` directory:

```
ebin_dir = <my_path_here>/erlang_yaws/multi_cast/_build/default/lib/multi_cast/ebin
```

Upon starting Yaws with `yaws -i` I can go to some simple `.yaws` files I've got which do not rely on any of the project´s `.beam` files. However, when I change my browser's location to a `.yaws` files which rely on the app's compiled files I get the following error:

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 21-Jan-2017::14:27:17 ===


ERROR erlang code threw an uncaught exception:
 File: <my_path_here>/erlang_yaws/multi_cast/htdocs/status.yaws:1
Class: exit
Exception: {noproc,{gen_server,call,[multi_cast_front,{get_etag}]}}
Req: {http_request,'GET',{abs_path,"/htdocs/status.yaws"},{1,1}}
Stack: [{gen_server,call,2,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,204}]},
        {m_27449121_1,out,1,
                      [{file,"<my_path_here>/.yaws/yaws/default/m_27449121_1.erl"},
                       {line,35}]},
        {yaws_server,deliver_dyn_part,8,
                     [{file,"yaws_server.erl"},{line,2872}]},
        {yaws_server,aloop,4,[{file,"yaws_server.erl"},{line,1242}]},
        {yaws_server,acceptor0,2,[{file,"yaws_server.erl"},{line,1065}]},
        {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,247}]}]
```

I believe this is due to the fact that my `gen_server` app isn't starting correctly or not being found? The source code seems to compile successfully.

I'm on MacOS Sierra with Yaws 2.0.4, Erlang 19 and I did a regular Yaws install with `homebrew`.

Also, is there a resource which thoroughly explains how to structure Yaws and a simple application? Reading both the manual and the book and both fail at explaining this (or I'm really thick), and it's quite frustrating to get stuck from a user experience viewpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You've correctly added your modules to the load path using the `ebin_dir` configuration variable, but that's not enough to actually start and run your application. The book you're following doesn't address this — see page 101, where it says, *"It is also possible to run Yaws as an OTP app inside an existing Erlang setup, but this is beyond the scope of this book."*

An easy way to start your server is to use the `runmod` configuration variable, documented in [the `yaws_config` man page](http://yaws.hyber.org/yman.yaws?page=yaws.conf):

> runmod = ModuleName
>     At startup Yaws will invoke  ModuleName:start() in a separate process. It is possible
>     to have several runmods. This is useful if we want to reuse the Yaws startup shell
>     script for our own application.

Assuming your `gen_server` provides a `start/0` function, set the name of your module as the value of `runmod` and Yaws will start it. A problem with this approach, though, is that it works fine for experimentation but not for production because there's nothing supervising your `gen_server`.

A better approach is to have a full OTP application running alongside Yaws. With this approach, your application's supervisors manage your workers. One way to do this is by using [yapps (Yaws applications)](http://yaws.hyber.org/yapp_intro.yaws). Another way is to [create a release](http://yaws.hyber.org/rebar_release.yaws) containing both Yaws and your application. Still another way is to [let Yaws supervise your workers](http://yaws.hyber.org/embed.yaws).

Addressing the second part of your question requires defining what you mean by "a simple application". Is it a simple static page application? A simple application using `.yaws` pages? A simple SSE application? A simple `appmod` application? A simple websocket application? A simple application running as a sibling of Yaws? There are a variety of possible definitions. The best short answer is to always structure your application using [OTP design principles](http://erlang.org/doc/design_principles/des_princ.html). You might also consider sending questions on this topic to the [Yaws mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/erlyaws-list).